# Enabling left and right swipe with angular-snap.js

Tags: angular, swipe, left-to-right

I am using the [Angular Snap.js](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js) library to enable a right and left swipe to perform certain actions on each side. The right side is working well, whereas I can't perform any action on the left side. The left side is open; I can't perform any action on that side. I also tested the example from the side and it is not working either.

Can anyone help? I am using Chrome 60 and Firefox 54. Thanks.

Here my code:

```
<div snap-drawer="left">
                    <div snap-close snap-id="'case'+customerCase.id" class="deleteCancelButton">
                        {{'list.cancel'| translate}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div snap-drawer="right">
                    <div snap-close snap-id="'case'+customerCase.id" class="deleteCancelButton">
                        {{'list.cancel'| translate}}
                    </div>
                    <div ng-click="delete(customerCase)" class="deleteButton">
                        {{'list.delete'| translate}}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I can swipe to the left and right. But I can't click on the left side. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPVX9.png)

Comment: would be great if you could send a demo with your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this before posting further: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: edit formatting, link structure, grammar